# Why is Mutiny call method blocking

Tags: java, mutiny

just get started with Mutiny, working through the guides (https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides). And as far as I read in the docs, the call method is async (https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/getting-started/observing-events).

However, with a small snippet it turns out that call method is blocking execution, so is not async from my understanding. Where is the mistake/misunderstanding here?

```
Uni.createFrom().item("bla")
      .onItem().invoke(i -> LOG.info("before call"))
      .onItem().call(i -> {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
        }
      )
      .subscribe().with(i -> LOG.info("after call process. result=" + i));
```

Log output

```
11:40:11.026 INFO [main] ....mutiny.vertx.HelloUni - before call
11:40:16.032 INFO [main] ....mutiny.vertx.HelloUni - after call process. result=bla
```

Answer (score 2):

Each subscriber (here we have 1 subscriber from main thread) will attempt (separately) to resolve the Uni. When it reaches the `call` lambda it simply blocks in the `Thread.sleep` call before creating the new Uni in the chain.

The functions passed to `.call` or `.transformToUni` are not supposed to block for I/O inside (`sleep` is doing that), but instead to initiate an I/O request and immediately return a Uni.

By the way, if we wanted to issue a delay (non-blocking), we could do something like:

```java
Uni<String> uni1 = Uni.createFrom().item("bla")
        .onItem().invoke(s -> logger.info("before call"))
        .onItem().delayIt().by(Duration.ofSeconds(3));

uni1.subscribe().with(s -> logger.info("after: result=" + s));
logger.info("main continues its work ...");
...
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I was not clear in my question. I was only putting the Thread.sleep to simulate a time consuming method, it is not about actually having a sleep. Basically seems like a misunderstood the docs understanding that call method would be executed async/non-blocking

Answer (score 1):

This is because does not auto-magically make your code asynchronous.

Here you block the thread before returning a `Uni`, so it is totally expected that you observe such a behaviour when you subscribe.